# Chromium ignores table height in css style or attribute height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chromium

I have jQuery ajax table, and I need to keep table height while its body isn't fully loaded. This is my code:

```
var tableHeight = parent.height();

// set parent fixed height so page don't jump up/down during adding
parent.height(tableHeight);
// or: parent.css("height", tableHeight + "px");

$tbody.hide().empty();
// no items loaded
if (rowsData.length === 0) {
    this._noItems();
} else {
    this._rowAdder(rowsData, actionDisplay);
}                                                                                

$tbody.show();                                                          
parent.height("auto");
```

- "parent" is table object

I know, I can use css attribute "visibility", but for example Mozilla doesn't change css style or table attribute and table displays well. My questions are: Why Chromium ignores configured css style or table attribute height? Can anybody help me, please? Ths ;)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height attribute is not as easy as setting the width.

In most cases you need to set the html and body heights to 100% if you want a child to know what 100% means.

```
html,body{
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sorry, this fix not helped.

Comment: If you could include some html and CSS it would go along way